# Excel File upload using Angular JS and Spring?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new to Angular JS but I have good experience in Spring MVC. So, now I have the requirement where I need to upload a file. But, here I need to develop UI screen for uploading excel sheet using AngulaJS and backend will be Spring controller. Can anyone provide example for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring, this would be the method to accept multipart file uploads. `myFile` will contain all information of the uploaded file you need.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{userId}/profile/image", method =   RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadProfileImage(@PathVariable String userId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile myFile) {
  ...

}
```

You might want to add the following Spring Bean to your setup, as well:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setResolveLazily(false);
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

In Angular, there are several projects that allow for file uploads.

Angular1:
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Angular2:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/tree/master/demo

Both easy to use with demos and samples on their github page.

Comment: In some cases you might have specific requirements for the resolution of multipart requests. For instance, we had some issues with encodings (default is ISO-8859-1 according to the servlet spec, not utf8).